# JQuery script to increase background position by 2000px every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

**Question**

I am trying to write a script that will increase the position of a certain element's background by 2600px every 7 seconds. The tricky part here is that I'm having trouble taking the measurement grabbed by using css("background-position") and increasing that number by the desired amount, since that should return the full measurement, including "px" - How can I fix this?

**My Script (very broken)**

```
var bgPosition =$('.header-slide-image').css("background-position");

setInterval(function() {
    var newBgposition = bgPosition+2600;
    $('.header-slide-image').delay(2000).css('background-position', "1400px");

}, 5000)
```

Comment: try this `css('background-position', "+=1400px")`...it will increase 1400px from existing position

Comment: Oh, great, didn't realize I could use that, thanks! (Beginner here)

Comment: Doesn't background-position have x and y?

Comment: Post that as an answer so we can close this Q

Comment: @PaulDraper used with only 1 measurement, CSS assumes horizontal position for some reason.

Comment: I looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp and I couldn't find any hint of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will increase the background position by 2000px every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var bgPosition = $('.header-slide-image').css("background-position");
    var bgNum = parseInt(bgPosition, 10);
    $('.header-slide-image').css('background-position', (bgNum + 2000) + "px");
}, 5000);
```

Changes from yours:

1. It gets the new background position each timer interval
2. It parses the background position into a number (which also drops the px at the end
3. Removed the delay since there appears to be no reason for that.  It's already in a delayed time interval.

You can also use the `+=` syntax added in jQuery 1.6

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.header-slide-image').css('background-position', "+=2000");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: FYI, your question mentions three different increment values and multiple time periods (one in title, others in body of question).  I presume you can adapt this to whatever you need.  Also, check the `+=` option too.

Comment: Yes, the different times in this case don't hurt the effect at all, thanks